# What is the mobile icon in Google search results?

Tags: html, seo

I'm creating a mobile version of my website. Sometimes while searching in Google I saw mobile icon in search results. I want to know what that mobile icon means and how to use it for my mobile version of website.

Comment: No, I don't have. I saw it in Google search at staring of result link.

Comment: The plain search results don't show any icons - sure you didn't look in the Images tab, or saw a video preview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my observations Mobile Icon means that website is compatible while browsing the site on cell phone with the help of GPRS.
For such sites, minimum look & feel features are provided and all the core functionality are included and are hosted on sub domains... Like for www.gmail.com, m.gmail.com is wap site....

You can browse such sites with the help of Cell Phones as well as PC's... You can find no or little difference. To Experience, browse them in your cell phone as well as in PC...

Examples for m sites: 
[m.gmail.com](http://m.gmail.com), [greatsites.mobi](http://greatsites.mobi), [surfwap.com](http://surfwap.com), [m.facebook.com](http://m.facebook.com),http://way2wap.com/